# Comparative Dynamics for system of linear ODEs in normal form in matrix form

Tags: comparative-statics, ode, dynamic

I have seen the use of comparative dynamics for systems of linear ODEs (for example, Wymer, 1976) in scalar form, usually in 2 dimensions. But I have not managed to find any worked example for a model consisting of an n-dimensional system of linear ODEs in normal form written in matrix form (Y' = AY + B). Could anyone please point me to any such example or show it step by step here?